# Harmonic sections of $\Omega_X^p\otimes E$ over a Kähler manifold

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles, kahler-manifolds, holomorphic-bundles

I am confused by an exercise in Huybrechts *Complex geometry: an introduction* regarding sections of a certain holomorphic vector bundle over a Kähler manifold, related to Hodge theory. The exercise is

> **Exercise 4.1.4.** Let ${E}\rightarrow X$ be a Hermitian ($h$) holomorphic vector bundle over a compact Kähler manifold $(X,\omega)$. Show that any holomorphic section $s\in H^0(X,\Omega_X^p\otimes {E})$ is harmonic.

The key definition is that of **harmonic**. As in the book, a (**smooth**!) section of the (**smooth!**) vector bundle $\Lambda^{p,q}X \otimes E$ is said to be harmonic if it is in the kernel of the Dolbeault-Laplacian operator
$$
\Delta_{E} = \bar{\partial}_E\bar{\partial}_E^* + \bar{\partial}^*_E \bar{\partial}_E,
$$
where $\bar{\partial}_E$ is the Dolbeault operator which encodes the holomorphic structure of the bundle $E$ and $^*$ refers to adjoint with respect to the $L^2$ inner product on **smooth** $E$-valued (p,q)-forms
$$
(\alpha,\beta)_{L^2} = \int_X (\alpha,\beta)_{h,\omega} \text{vol}
$$
which is inherited from the Hermitian structures on $E$ and $\Lambda^{p,q}X$ the smooth complex bundle of (p,q)-forms.

Note that $\Omega_X^p$ is, as in the book, the *holomorphic* vector bundle of *holomorphic* p-forms, i.e., those (p,0)-forms which are $\bar{\partial}$-closed.

**My previous and seemingly naive attempt:**

If $s\in H^0(X,\Omega_X^p\otimes E)$ is a holomorphic section, it is necessarily a section of the **smooth** vector bundle $\Lambda^{p,0}X \otimes E$. We can check the condition locally, and it is sufficient to check that $s$ is $\bar{\partial}_E$ and $\bar{\partial}_E^*$ closed. The latter is easy, as $s$ is an $E$-valued (p,0)-form, $\bar{\partial}_E^*$ kills it since there are no $(p,-1)$-forms. To check that $\bar{\partial}_E$ also kills $s$, we reason locally.

We aim to impose holomorphicity of $s$, we need to check that it is annihilated by the Dolbeault operator of the tensor product! Since the Dolbeault operator of the bundle of forms is simply the usual Dolbeault operator on the base $\bar{\partial}$, we have that
$$
\bar{\partial}_{\Omega_X^p \otimes E} = \bar{\partial} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes \bar{\partial}_E
$$
and applying to a section of the form $s=\alpha\otimes \varphi$ for $\alpha$ a (local) p-form and $\varphi$ a (local) section of $E$ we obtain
$$
0 = \bar{\partial} \alpha \otimes \varphi + \alpha \otimes \bar{\partial}_E \varphi\qquad (*)
$$
What I am missing is **(1)** how to use this to deduce that the extension to $E$-valued higher-forms of $\bar{\partial}_E$ annihilates $\alpha\otimes \varphi$. Recall that this extension gives a $p$-graded Leibniz rule
$$
\bar{\partial}_E(\alpha\otimes \varphi) = \bar{\partial}\alpha \otimes \varphi +(-1)^p \alpha\otimes \bar{\partial}_E \varphi
$$
I suspect I have a deep misunderstanding regarding this.
**(2)** Where do I even need the Kähler condition that Huybrechts uses in the statement of the problem?

Comment: Because the manifold is Kähler, the “usual” Laplacian and the $\bar\partial$ Laplacian are equal up to a scalar multiple. I don’t see the issue with the Leibniz rule (although the second term needs to be skew-symmetrized). $\bar\partial_E$ annihilates both factors by holomorphicity.

Comment: However, the fact that the usual Laplacian and the $\bar{\partial}$ Laplacian, even proportional in the Kähler case... how does this tell us anything about the Laplacian on vector-bundle valued forms $\Delta_{\bar{\partial}_E}$?

Also, how can I deduce $\bar{\partial}\alpha$ and $\bar{\partial}\varphi$ vanish from condition (*)?

Comment: To add to Ted's comment, we can work in a local _holomorphic_ frame $(e_{j})_{j=1}^{k}$ for $E$; a holomorphic $E$-valued $p$-form is then an expression $\sum_{j} \alpha^{j} e_{j}$ with $\alpha^{j}$ denoting holomorphic $p$-forms on $X$.